# org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch and Spring Jdbc, A few chunks works fine, but I get the below error: I am simply reading from Postgres DB and writting to Postgres DB

Error:

```
2022-02-02 22:00:45.375 ERROR 12308 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.u.r.i.r.c.d.w.SecurityDataItemWriter   : #### Exception Occured while saving to BD : 
2022-02-02 22:00:45.384 ERROR 12308 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : JobRepository failure forcing rollback

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]; This connection has been closed.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:236) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.updateExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:163) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext(SimpleJobRepository.java:218) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) [spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) [spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this?  Would be great if you can tell us how you did.